# what is the formula for local vol , as a function of implied vol, AND why am i getting a negative denominator?

Tags: local-volatility, local

i am seeing different formulas at different places on stack exchange, so not sure!
eg if denominator has a term y^2/w^2, or y/w^2 or 
1/w or -1/w

and also, whatever formula i use, i get a negative denominator for the following (which has no arbitrage), so i wonder why it doesnt work?
T=1,F=100,K1=95,K2=100,VOL1=27%,VOL2=22%
and i am evaluating local vol at K1,T
(ie so the 2nd derivative term is zero)

i guess AFK's answer at [Local volatility surface corresponding to the implied volatility surface](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16898/local-volatility-surface-corresponding-to-the-implied-volatility-surface/53516#53516) may be correct, as for his, it does not fail in my above example!
[image]

i wonder why this derivation would be wrong! https://www.frouah.com/finance%20notes/Dupire%20Local%20Volatility.pdf

[image]

Comment: The expression below seems correct, based on [another unrelated source](http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/ctff03/Gatheral.1.pdf) having the same result (I can't spot any cross referencing) in [the lecture notes by Jim Gatheral](http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/ctff03/Gatheral.1.pdf), although the derivation in @AFK's answer skips a lot of steps, so it's not unrealistic there is a typo.

Comment: your formula is in fact a THIRD formula!!!!  :(