# Strike arbitrage in discrete implied volatility grid

Tags: implied-volatility, arbitrage

I need to test strike (butterfly) arbitrage on a **discrete** implied volatility grid.

I know that the traditional procedure for continuous case is (for a given maturity T):

1. See the Dupire formula in terms of implied volatility (and not in terms of option prices). You can find it [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16898/local-volatility-surface-corresponding-to-the-implied-volatility-surface).
2. Check if the denominator of Dupire formula is positive for every K

The Dupire denominator from step 2 contains derivatives, thus it relies on the fact that the implied volatility surface is continuous.

Now, back to my discrete grid of implied volatility.
How can I transform step 2 (with derivatives), in a condition adapted for discrete grid?

Comment: Not sure if you'd be satisfied with smoothing the IV surface in an arbitrage-free way. If you are, then this may help: https://core.ac.uk/reader/6978470

Comment: Absence of arbitrage must hold, irrespective of a discrete or continuous vol surface. For a discrete surface, no-arbitrage dictates positive second (weighted) differences, AFAIR